# How to send NULL as :string in cffi

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

I'm trying to use wayland-client from lisp side, this is my code:

```
(define-foreign-library wayland-client
  (:unix (:or "libwayland-client.so.0.20.0" "libwayland-client.so"))
  (t (:default "libwayland-client")))


(use-foreign-library wayland-client)

(defcfun "wl_display_connect" :pointer
  (name :string))

(wl-display-connect (null-pointer));;return NULL
```

Code in C, come from [here](https://jan.newmarch.name/Wayland/ProgrammingClient/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wayland-client.h>

struct wl_display *display = NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    display = wl_display_connect(NULL);
    if (display == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't connect to display\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("connected to display\n");

    wl_display_disconnect(display);
    printf("disconnected from display\n");    
    exit(0);
}
```

I have test the C one and it worked, how should the lisp one be correct?

How `wl_display_connect` been defined from [here](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/apb.html#Client-classwl__display_1a8a14a809eb2c083a806db2ee15523041)

```
struct wl_display* wl_display_connect(const char *name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on CFFI but I think the trick is to say that things are `(:pointer :char)`s not `:string`s.  Given this trivial C function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *ts(char *x) {
  if (x == NULL) {
    printf("Got a null\n");
  }
  return x;
}
```

And this CFFI declaration:

```lisp
(defcfun (ts "ts")
    (:pointer :char)
  (name (:pointer :char)))
```

Then this will work:

```
> (null-pointer-p (ts (null-pointer)))
Got a null
t
```

And you can then call it with foreign strings, but you need to deal with allocating and deallocating them: `(ts "foo")` won't work.  But this will:

```lisp
(defun ts-wrapper (s)
  (with-foreign-string (x s)
    (foreign-string-to-lisp (ts x))))
```

And now:

```
> (ts-wrapper "foo")
"foo"
3
```

Obviously in your case you don't need to deal with the conversion back from the foreign string.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, according to thist https://github.com/cffi/cffi/discussions/316, it is because my emacs was built with X, but not wayland. I have test the code in a wayland terminal, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(cffi:null-pointer)` since string is a pointer to char array.